# How to map inheritence in JPA with more that one sequence?

Tags: inheritance, jpa, sequence

I have an abstract class A that many other classes inherits it.
In our DB (Oracle), these classes are mapped by a table per class, and the inheritance is implemented by an FK in the child table (FK on the child's PK referencing A's PK).
So far so good. Pretty standard.

Now, how do we generate the PK? with a sequence of course... but our DBA decided that when creating rows in a specific table B which inherits A, the PK will be generated from a different sequence (B's sequence).

My question - how to map this in JPA? I want class B to inherit class A, but when it's instantiated I want its ID (which is A's ID) to be generated using a different sequence.

Answer (score 0):

JPA does not provide a way to override the sequence generator in a subclass.

You could make the superclass a @MappedSuperclass, and not define the id in it, then you could define it differently in the subclass.

If using EclipseLink, you could define a DescriptorCustomizer (@Customizer) on the subclass and set the sequenceName on the descriptor to the other sequence.

Comment: This will not work, as the JPA will not create a row in A's table (because it's not an entity). And I'm using Kodo, so the EclipseLink feature is irrelevant for me :(