# JPA Eclipselink TableGenerator in hierarchy - one generator per class

Tags: eclipselink, hierarchy

I'm working with EclipseLink 2.6.1-RC1, I have a class hierarchy that will illustrate below:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;
    .... irrelevant code ....
}
@Entity
public class Coupon extends AbstractEntity {
 ---- irrelevant ...
}
@Entity
public class Sector extends AbstractEntity {
 .... irrelevant ...
}
```

I need to use TableGenerator for id generation purpose. But what I need is that there was a record for each child class in the table of "Sequences". I allready search in different places, but nothing. I know that if i split the declaration of "id" field on every child class it works, but i have moooore of two childrens jaja.

Any help? thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, after keep searching, i found other's questions similars to mine, but with no answers, and i found a bug in eclipselink due 2013 with this funtionality without further information of release version. 
But, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9113475/5310409), tells that we can use "Customizer" to change several things of JPA descriptors, so, i change the sequence name in that form, and its works perfect!

```
public class SequenceCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) throws Exception {
        descriptor.setSequenceNumberName(descriptor.getTableName());

    }
}
```